# Hide system process executed by c program

Tags: c, unix

I need to create a program that starts a system command without starting a new pid. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\n***************************************\n");

    system("sleep 60");
    return 0;
}
```

If I look at process monitor I can see:

```
[root@dev ~]# ps axw | grep sleep
 1655 pts/0    S+     0:00 sleep 60
```

Is there a way to "mask" the process? The goal is to start a command that has a password as argument so I would like to be able to hide it.

Comment: It might be possibly if you recreate the `system` function with a minor change. First of all you need to learn about processes, how to create them (the `fork` system call) and how to execute external programs (the `exec` family of functions). Then consider the arguments you pass to the `exec` function, and what you pass for `argv[0]` to the external program and how it might affect what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The only robust solution is not to put passwords on the command-line at all.

While many utilities do accept passwords this way, it's hard to think of any way this practice can be justified on security grounds -- not in a production environment, anyway. It's difficult to hide process commands lines from somebody who is determined to see them, and they have a nasty habit of turning up in log files and other diagnostics.

If you need to run a utility that takes a password, see if there is any other way to pass credentials -- perhaps an encrypted password file or, in more modern practice, a client certificate. If the utility you need to run does not provide a way to supply passwords except on the command line, ask the developer to fix it.

On Linux, there is no safe, robust way to do what you propose.

Comment: The goal is to call an .exe executable on a remote windows server from linux.I wrote a script in python which, starting from domain \ username and password, launches commands on the remote server. The problem is that I have to mask the user's password, if I compile the python with pyinstaller I can create a binary executable but the disassembly is much easier than a binary compiled in c, that's why my choice.
By following the guide here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403918/119298) I managed to get what I was looking for. Is it safe to use LD_PRELOAD? I'm sorry but I'm not very experienced

Comment: If you're using C on LInux, and you're prepared to do something really ugly, and you're writing the program yourself, then you can hide the arguments from `ps` and `/proc/xxx/cmdline` simply by overwriting them (copy them first, of course). These arguments are in a segment your program can write. But I don't see how any of this help with a Windows executable.

Comment: I have a linux and a windows machine, from linux I have to call an executable .exe present inside the windows machine and let it run on the remote windows server. I call it through pywinrm with username password and windows server ip